# Adding an element to the end of an ordered list

Tags: c, list

I have just started learning about dynamic structures in C. 
The first type that I'm trying to learn is the ordered list. I have created a few functions - namely, adding nodes to the beginning of the list and printing elements in the list, but then I decided to write a function that allows me to add elements to the end of the list. My function looks like this:

```
typedef struct Node* Node;

void add_end(Node *head, int value) {
   Node new;
   new = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
   new -> value = value;
   new -> next = NULL;
   if(*head == NULL) {
      *head = new;
   }

   else {
      Node help = *head;
      while(help->next != NULL) {
         help = help->next;
      }
      help->next = new;
   }
}
```

Some clarification: My structure consists of two fields - value (int) and next (pointer to the next node). 
Thus, my questions are: 
1) Notice my substitution using the variable called "help" - when I tried to do this without it,namely writing  `*head` wherever `help` appears now, and this function did not work properly - it only added as much as two elements. For example, if I pushed 1, 3, 5, 7 to the list, only 5 and 7 would be added. Why was this so? I really can't see any reasonable explanation. 
2) At first I tried passing an argument of the type `Node` to the function (Not `Node*` as I'm doing now) and the function did not put anything to the list. Once again, I can't see the difference between writing using the type Node and writing the variable without the asterisk. Could you explain it to me in layman terms? 
 
I know that my question may have a trivial answer, but please, be understanding - this is my first encounter with pointers and they may be quite complex to comprehend.

Comment: If you want an ordered list it makes no sense to have an `add_end` function. You just want an `add` and then find where the element goes

Comment: You are making the code even harder to read and comprehend by "hiding" pointer types under innocently sounding type names like `Node`. Avoid `typedef`-ing pointer types without a good reason to do so. Keep those `*`  in the open so that people know that they are working with pointers.

Comment: @4386427
I guess I may have used the wrong terminology in the title - I thought that "linked list" and "ordered list" were the same.

Comment: No LinkedList is a data structure consist of a node to the next. Ordered List is basically a sorted list

Comment: @Aemilius - They are very different. An ordered list involves some kind of sorting (e.g. lowest value always at front) while linked list in unordered (i.e. elements can be in any order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try to answer your two questions:

1. Because you typedefed Node as `typedef struct Node* Node;` what you are passing into `add_end` as the first parameter is a double pointer to `struct Node` (like `struct Node**`). You then dereference it in your while loop with `Node help = *head;` This means that the value of the actual pointer is going to change. If you didn't have the `help` pointer, you would then keep moving `head` until you get to the end of the list. This means that you would only have two elements in the list -- the head itself and its `next` element.
2. The answer to this has to do with your typedef again. When you pass `Node`, with your typedef, you are only passing a single pointer to `struct Node` representing head, which means that dereferencing it will not give you the pointer to head, but the structure itself, which means that neither your `if` or `else` statements will work as intended, as your intent is to compare pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Your function type should probably be:

```
void add_end(Node **head, int value) {
                   ^
```

because `head` is a pointer to `Node`

Like:

```
void add_end(Node **head, int value) {
   Node* new;                                 // NOTICE Node*
   new = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
   // TODO - add check for new being NULL
   new -> value = value;
   new -> next = NULL;
   if(*head == NULL) {
      *head = new;
   }
   else {
      Node help = *head;
      while(help->next != NULL) {
         help = help->next;
      }
      help->next = new; 
   }
}
```

and call it like:

```
Node* head = NULL;

add_end(&head, 42);
add_end(&head, 42);
add_end(&head, 42);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it work properly if we didn't use the "help" variable, but wrote "*head* wherever "help" appears?

Comment: @Aemilius - Because `help` and `head` are different types. One is pointer and the other is pointer-to-pointer.